# react typescript create ref to access state of child

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to access the state of child component in the parent component, I don't want to use any handlers in child component that can set a variable in parent or I don't want to lift the state up in parent. How can I use ref in react typescript to createRef and get the child's state in the parent component?

Parent:

```
export interface ParentProps {}

interface State {
    counter?: number
}

export class Parent extends React.Component<ParentProps, State> {
    private readonly childRef: React.RefObject<**what should I put here?**>
    constructor(props: ParentProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            counter: undefined
        }
        this.childRef = React.createRef<**what should I put here**>();
    }

    render(){
        <Child ref={childRef} **<- (this throws an error)** counter={this.state.counter}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})}>
             add
        </button>
    }
}
```

Child:

```
export interface ChildProps {
  counter: number
}
    
interface State {
  some state variable that should be accessible in parent
}
    
export class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps, State> {
   some methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
this.childRef = React.createRef<Child>(null);
```

---

```
render(){
        <Child ref={this.childRef}  counter={this.state.counter} />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})}>
             add
        </button>
    }
```

---

```
private readonly childRef: React.RefObject<Child>
```

or

```
private readonly childRef: React.RefObject<Child>()
```

Comment: Doesn't help this, what needs to be added in the type React.RefObject<**what should I put here?**> ??

Comment: I have updated the answer with 2 ways of handling "React.RefObject<**what should I put here?**>". Please try

Comment: This introduces new error: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?